# How to enable video recording on AWS Chime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to integrate video calling in my app using AWS Chime and calling is working well. But now I want to record the video and send it to bucket and already tried WebMMediaRecording and MediaRecording classes but no luck, can I get some help here?

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? What did you try and what difficulties did you encounter? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: did you get any solutions? I also want to implement same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful recording video and screen sharing using: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk-recording-demo

Notes:

- When creating AWS Cloud9 environment you must specify a compatible zone in Network settings (advanced) Subnet. I used 1a.
- When deploying the Serverless test app you must use different names to not override the API Gateway configuration of the SDK (/recording).

Comment: can you specify names of which resource should be different..also how to get compatible zone?

Comment: <my-stack-name> has to be different. For the zone, you can set it to No Preference and let AWS manage it. After multiple tries, I stopped doing the Cloud 9 step. I use AWS CLI and Docker from my machine to create the ECR repository and the subsequent steps.

Comment: amazon-chime-sdk-recordin-demo specifies that it creates a bot which joins meeting using headless browser and records the meeting and screensharing.. is that how you did it? can you share code?

Comment: Update: Amazon recently added capture capability to Chime. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/business-productivity/capture-amazon-chime-sdk-meetings-using-media-capture-pipelines/